# Elasticsearch: Comparing two fields of the same document, where one of the fields is inside a nested document

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

Consider the following document:

```
{
    "group" : "fans",
    "preferredFanId" : 1,
    "user" : [
        {
            "fanId" : 1,
            "first" : "John",
            "last" :  "Smith"
        },
        {
            "fanId" : 2,
            "first" : "Alice",
            "last" :  "White"
        },
    ]
}
```

where "`user`" is a nested document.  I want to get `inner_hits` (from 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT) where `preferredFanId == user.fanId` , and so I want only the John Smith record returned in the `inner_hits`.

Is it possible?  I've tried several approaches like using "`include_in_parent`" or "`_source`", but nothing seems to work.

Comment: This doesn't sound like something Elasticsearch would be able to do. This seems to be a relational database specific request.

Comment: Do you have defined user as type "nested"? Could you post your mapping?